# ADO.NET Entity Data Model are not precise enough

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

I run this code:

```
var cos = from k in _db.klienci_do_trasy where k.klient_id == 5 select k;
```

but the query send to database is:

```
    SELECT * FROM `klienci_do_trasy`
 LIMIT 0, 30
```

why is it for, there is no condition on klient_id?

Answer (score 1):

What database are you using? If this is really the case, there could be an error in the provider.